# How can I check OPA memory usage with big file size?

Tags: benchmarking, opa

I know that benchmarking in OPA shows memory usage as B/op. I want to see how much memory it takes up on actual memory when the file size of data.json is large + how much memory it consumes when calculating if the file is large, how can I check it? Does B/op include all the usage I want?
`opa bench --data policy.rego --data data.json --input input.json 'data.opa.allow' --count 1 --benchmem`

[image: bench result]

Tried OPA benchmark command